# SSIS Excel wont Refresh Values

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, ssis, ssis-2012

having an issue with SSIS Excel wont Refresh Values

the values all are 0 when opening , when i do the Ctrl , Alt F9 ...they all calculate

they are formatted as general cells , (same when changed to number issue happens)

there are no Text values being entered

excel settings for calculation is set to automatic too

any ideas team?

or is there a C# script task i can add, if yes can please provide

Regards

Comment: It sounds like the calculation mode is set to manual https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/current-mode-of-calculation  Confirm/deny?

Comment: Hi, the setting is already set to automatic please advise